# octave RMS function not recognized

Tags: octave

Folks,
It seems that rms function is not yet implemented in octave's signal package.

```
>> y = rms(x)^2
warning: the 'rms' function belongs to the signal package from Octave Forge but
has not yet been implemented.

Please read `http://www.octave.org/missing.html' to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.

error: 'rms' undefined near line 1 column 5
```

Any idea how I can implement my own custom function to calculate rms value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some [patches on the patch tracker](http://savannah.gnu.org/patch/?func=detailitem&item_id=8636) which implements rms:

snip:

```
function y = rms (varargin)
  if (nargin != 1 && nargin != 2)
    print_usage ();
  endif
  y = sqrt (meansq (varargin{:}));
endfunction
```